# Inner pages of ionic 3doesn't work with script or external custom jQuery plugin in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I use script tag in index. Html it will work on first or root pages of ionic 3 after I push navctrl to another pages the script doesn't work with that second or inner pages of ionic 3  how to use custom jQuery plugin or any for inner pages of ionic or I want to use script in inner pages of ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

We should declare $ as globally and after ionviewdidload we call the custom plugin method it should work